# Clickable link in shell window?

Tags: shell

I see some graphical shell environments allow you to click hyperlinks appearing in text output from running applications.

I would think that outputting anything http://... like would probably make a clickable link, but are there any other standards/mechanisms I should look at? Ideally I would like to do linktext and have "linktext" appear as clickable.

I'd appreciate something cross-platform compatible with appropriate fallback mechanisms, and I'll read any programming language but prefer java.

Comment: Please include a link to examples. Never have seen this before. You might also want to add a tag for the windowing system you have seen this in. Good luck.

Comment: I think you've used a wrong term here. A shell is usually defined as a program that starts other programs. Hence, a graphical shell would refer to software like the Windows task bar, GNOME panel or Mac OS X dock.

Comment: As far as i know, the terminal emulators have this feature hard-coded. Extending it is probably barely an option. Doing this platform-independently now is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using cygwin's mintty shell (Windows environment's Linux-like shell), you could `Ctrl+click` on any plain text that is URL or (possibly relative) file path, but without spaces in between.

E.g. in mintty shell, type "http://google.com" OR "path/to/file.txt" (relative to current directory) and `Ctrl+click` on the text.  It will open the URL or the file by your default application.

Answer (score 0):

There are different software layers messed up together in your question. The shell layer is cross platform compatible which is assured by standard as POSIX. But the "shell window", how you call it, is accomplished by particular terminal - like linux console (which is not window at all), xterm, windows putty, gnome-terminal etc. At this level, there is nothing like compatibility, on the contrary, it's complete diversity. I know that **gnome-terminal** had this feature you wanted - one was able to configure which characters are still part of the link and which do not. But you hardly achieve a compatibility here, unless the particular terminal is available for all the platforms...

Comment: My question is not messed up, it's precise ;)

Comment: OK :-) (but I only said the software layers were messed up in the question, not the question itself :-))